# Recommended way to solve common requirements of a many-to-many relation with Spring Data

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Aim of this question is to share our experience on how to solve the (i think common) requirements with Spring Data.

Given the following many-to-many relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BookCategory> categories;

    // rest omitted for clarity
}

@Entity
public class Category {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    // rest omitted for clarity
}

@Entity
public class BookCategory {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Category category;

    int ordering = 0;

    // rest omitted for clarity
}
```

Search requirements:

- get all books
- get books with category A and B (number of categories to search for is dynamic) order by BookCategory.ordering
- get books with category B order by Book.name

When the book is used in the application, the assigned categories need to be always shown.

My questions are

- which query building mechanism solves the requirements best? (@Query, Query by example, direct EntityManager usage, ...)
- how does the search query look like?
- how to avoid the n+1 problem when using the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which query building mechanism solves the requirements best?

Use Spring Data's Specification or use QueryDSL library

> how does the search query look like?

```
SELECT b.* from Book where exists (select 1 from bookCategory bc where bc.book_id=b.id and bc.category_id in (:catList) group by bc.book_id having count(bc.book_id) = (:catListSize));
```

> how to avoid the n+1 problem when using the book?

use eager fetch book -> BookCategory